# Automatic setting of greek letters in \begin{} environment

Tags: texstudio, bugs

I am not quite sure, what happened, but I was working on some equations, and all of a sudden, TexStudio became buggy.
It automatically writes all I write in the \begin{} statement in greek letters (see screenshot). If I look at the .tex file in gedit or in overleaf, everything is normal, but Texstudio just sets greek, and also interprets it like greek (so pdflatex fails). [image: screenshot of small example code]
This bug does also seem to be with every document I want to work with in TexStudio.
I am using TeXstudio 2.6.6 (hg 4099), Qt Version 4.8.6, compiled with Qt 4.8.4 D.

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,11pt,ngerman,english]{scrbook}%{report}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{showkeys} % remove for final version
\usepackage{subfiles} %for mother/child nesting of the document
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib} %citation style from journal template

\begin{document}document
\begin{equation} %Equation
a = b+c 
\end{equation}
\begin{table} %table
\begin{tabular}{ll} %tabular
a&b \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\huge{TEST} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

This it the code e.g. in gedit

Maybe someone can help me to fix this?

Comment: texstudio has a bug tracker: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues. Report such issues there.

Comment: Before you do, update your TXS to the latest version first (2.12.10) and see if the bug persists.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with `Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Syntax Highlighting`, then check for `environment` under `Basic highlighting`. The Font Family is probably set to a different font than `<default>`.

Comment: @Max        thank you, you were right. If you want to, change your comment to an answer and I can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to a setting in `Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Syntax Highlighting`. Check for `environment` under `Basic highlighting`. The font family there is probably set to a font with Greek letters, instead of `<default>`.

In my (Windows) version this looks like:

[image]